# Scrolling through id with link not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, typescript

currently i am using id to scroll to the particular section of the page but whenever i click it is not aligned to the top of page but going to the middle of page.
suppose my link is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
whenever i click the link first time with no id present on link , it scrolls to centre of page but when id is present in link like [www.example.com#id](http://www.example.com#id) then it works totally fine

my code

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#glossary-body-content">${dto.pageInfo.title} - Definition with Examples</a></li>
  <#if dto.adhocFaqs?size != 0>
  <li><a href="#glossary-faq-section">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
  </#if>
  <#if dto.practiceQuestions?size != 0>
  <li><a href="#glossary-question-answer-section">Practice Problems</a></li>
  </#if>
</ul>
```

can anyone tell how to fix this with js or css

Comment: is in viewport or not? If your `target` element is already in viewport `<a href="#target"> Take me there </a>` this code will not work!!

Comment: yes it is in viewport but at the middle of the page